# Make a custom modebar button icon in plotly graphs

Tags: r, icons, plotly

**Heavily edited**

How do you make a custom modebar button icon in plotly graphs?

There is some documentation [here][1], but it is unclear how to take a different icon or image, and use that for your icon in the modebar. How do you do this?

Comment: I appreciate that this was a lot of work, and there is lots of good info here, but I'm not sure this is very suited for the Q&A format here. Typically we'd want a single question with a minimal example, while this reads more like a blog post. It might be better to break these up into separate questions, and you can answer some of those yourself.

Comment: Fair call. I think it would make a great blog post with the questions answered. Even better, the answers are integrated into either the plotly book or web documentation. I'll see if I get a chance to break it up soon.

Comment: Cut down version of some key questions here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59185940/4927395

Comment: The original question here substantially cut down to describe process of getting a path and assigning it to an object in R that can then be used as a custom icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *Get icon image path*

   If you are using an icon that is already in [svg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) format (e.g. from [here](https://svgicons.sparkk.fr/)), you can copy the path (which is the instructions on how to draw the icon) into R and assign it to an object:

   [image: download icon]

   ```
   dl_icon_svg_path = "M15.608,6.262h-2.338v0.935h2.338c0.516,0,0.934,0.418,0.934,0.935v8.879c0,0.517-0.418,0.935-0.934,0.935H4.392c-0.516,0-0.935-0.418-0.935-0.935V8.131c0-0.516,0.419-0.935,0.935-0.935h2.336V6.262H4.392c-1.032,0-1.869,0.837-1.869,1.869v8.879c0,1.031,0.837,1.869,1.869,1.869h11.216c1.031,0,1.869-0.838,1.869-1.869V8.131C17.478,7.099,16.64,6.262,15.608,6.262z M9.513,11.973c0.017,0.082,0.047,0.162,0.109,0.226c0.104,0.106,0.243,0.143,0.378,0.126c0.135,0.017,0.274-0.02,0.377-0.126c0.064-0.065,0.097-0.147,0.115-0.231l1.708-1.751c0.178-0.183,0.178-0.479,0-0.662c-0.178-0.182-0.467-0.182-0.645,0l-1.101,1.129V1.588c0-0.258-0.204-0.467-0.456-0.467c-0.252,0-0.456,0.209-0.456,0.467v9.094L8.443,9.553c-0.178-0.182-0.467-0.182-0.645,0c-0.178,0.184-0.178,0.479,0,0.662L9.513,11.973z"
   ```

   If you have a logo (png or some random image file type), the first step is to turn it into an svg path. You can do this in an image editor like [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) (open source) by importing/pasting your image in. 
   Then use [path] [trace] command to create the path. You may end up with multiple paths. As far as I am aware, you probably want a single path, and you may need to accept it will end up as a single colour.

   To make a single path, use the [path] [combine] command. It may help to adjust the canvas size. Save your file, and open the file in a text editor (eg notepad) and copy out the path (should look similar to example above).
2. *Scale and adjust image*

   In R, you may need to scale and adjust your image. This is a bit of guesswork, but the snippet of code to do this would look something like this, with scale factor behaving as expected, and translate moving the image in x and y direction respectively:

   ```
   icon = list(
       path = dl_icon_svg_path,
       transform = "scale(0.84) translate(-1, -1)"
       )
   ```

   Note, by default any image you convert into svg is probably way bigger in px scale than an icon default. There are also controls to flip the image, as a result of some historical defaults, though this may have been fixed - hard to tell from the javascript discussions [here](https://community.plot.ly/t/adding-a-button-to-modebarbuttons-with-cutom-image/401).
3. *Change shape or dimensions of icon to display, Control colour of icon,Make icon download data or open link in new window*

   These options are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59253529/4927395)
4. *Additional Customisation*

   - Multiple buttons is straightforward via a list:

     ```
     config(modeBarButtonsToAdd = list(mc_button,dl_button))
     ```
   - Order of buttons
   - Display of modebar
     Hide the modebar is described here. Always show the modebar is done by the reverse, i.e.:

     ```
     config(displayModeBar = TRUE)
     ```

---

Here is a self contained rmarkdown example you can copy and knit:

````
---
title: "Custom icons in Plotly"
output: html_document
---

```{r echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
    Time = round(runif(10), 2),
    Value = round(runif(10), 2),
    Type = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 5)
    )

gg <- ggplot(data = data) +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = Time, y = Value, colour = Type), size = 2)

# (1) svg path copied from svg file opened in notepad

# logo-mastercard.svg from https://github.com/plotly/plotly-icons/tree/master/src/svg
mc_icon_svg_path = "M29.375 16c0-1.438-0.375-2.813-1.063-4.063-0.75-1.188-1.75-2.125-2.938-2.875-1.313-0.688-2.625-1.063-4-1.063-1.813 0-3.438 0.563-4.875 1.625 1.313 1.188 2.125 2.563 2.563 4.188h-0.75c-0.375-1.375-1.125-2.688-2.313-3.75-1.188 1.063-1.938 2.375-2.313 3.75h-0.75c0.438-1.625 1.25-3 2.563-4.188-1.438-1.063-3.063-1.625-4.875-1.625-1.375 0-2.688 0.375-4 1.063-1.188 0.75-2.188 1.688-2.938 2.875-0.688 1.25-1.063 2.625-1.063 4.063s0.375 2.813 1.063 4.063c0.75 1.188 1.75 2.125 2.938 2.875 1.313 0.688 2.625 1.063 4 1.063 1.813 0 3.438-0.563 4.875-1.625-1.188-1.063-2-2.313-2.5-3.875h0.75c0.438 1.313 1.188 2.5 2.25 3.438 1.063-0.938 1.813-2.125 2.25-3.438h0.75c-0.5 1.563-1.313 2.813-2.5 3.875 1.438 1.063 3.063 1.625 4.875 1.625 1.375 0 2.688-0.375 4-1.063 1.188-0.75 2.188-1.688 2.938-2.875 0.688-1.25 1.063-2.625 1.063-4.063zM6.125 14.063h1.25l-0.625 3.875h-0.813l0.5-2.938-1.063 2.938h-0.625v-2.938l-0.5 2.938h-0.813l0.688-3.875h1.188v2.375zM9.875 15.688c0 0.188-0.063 0.375-0.063 0.563-0.063 0.313-0.125 0.625-0.188 0.875 0 0.25-0.063 0.438-0.125 0.625v0.188h-0.625v-0.375c-0.188 0.313-0.5 0.438-0.875 0.438-0.25 0-0.375-0.063-0.5-0.188-0.188-0.188-0.25-0.438-0.25-0.688 0-0.375 0.125-0.688 0.375-0.875 0.313-0.188 0.688-0.313 1.125-0.313h0.313v-0.188c0-0.188-0.188-0.25-0.563-0.25-0.188 0-0.5 0-0.813 0.125 0-0.188 0.063-0.438 0.125-0.688 0.313-0.125 0.625-0.188 0.938-0.188 0.75 0 1.125 0.313 1.125 0.938zM8.938 16.5h-0.188c-0.438 0-0.688 0.188-0.688 0.5 0 0.188 0.063 0.313 0.25 0.313s0.313-0.063 0.438-0.188c0.125-0.125 0.188-0.313 0.188-0.625zM12.188 14.813l-0.125 0.75c-0.188-0.063-0.375-0.063-0.625-0.063s-0.375 0.063-0.375 0.25c0 0.063 0 0.125 0.063 0.188l0.25 0.125c0.375 0.25 0.563 0.5 0.563 0.875 0 0.688-0.375 1.063-1.25 1.063-0.375 0-0.688-0.063-0.813-0.063 0-0.188 0.063-0.438 0.125-0.75 0.313 0.063 0.563 0.125 0.688 0.125 0.313 0 0.5-0.063 0.5-0.25 0-0.063-0.063-0.188-0.063-0.188-0.125-0.125-0.188-0.188-0.375-0.188-0.375-0.188-0.563-0.5-0.563-0.875 0-0.688 0.375-1.063 1.188-1.063 0.375 0 0.688 0 0.813 0.063zM13.438 14.813h0.375l-0.063 0.813h-0.438c0 0.188-0.063 0.375-0.063 0.563 0 0.063-0.063 0.125-0.063 0.25 0 0.188-0.063 0.25-0.125 0.313v0.25c0 0.188 0.125 0.25 0.313 0.25 0.063 0 0.125 0 0.25-0.063l-0.125 0.75c-0.125 0-0.313 0.063-0.625 0.063-0.438 0-0.625-0.25-0.625-0.688 0-0.25 0-0.563 0.125-0.875l0.313-2.063h0.813zM16.375 15.875c0 0.313 0 0.563-0.063 0.813h-1.625c0 0.188 0.063 0.375 0.125 0.438 0.125 0.125 0.313 0.188 0.563 0.188 0.313 0 0.563-0.063 0.875-0.25l-0.125 0.813c-0.188 0.063-0.5 0.125-0.875 0.125-0.875 0-1.375-0.5-1.375-1.375 0-0.625 0.125-1.063 0.438-1.375 0.25-0.313 0.563-0.5 0.938-0.5s0.688 0.125 0.875 0.313c0.188 0.188 0.25 0.438 0.25 0.813zM14.75 16h0.938v-0.188l-0.063-0.125c0-0.063-0.063-0.125-0.063-0.125-0.063 0-0.125-0.063-0.188-0.063h-0.125c-0.25 0-0.438 0.125-0.5 0.5zM18.438 14.813c-0.063 0.063-0.125 0.375-0.313 0.938-0.188-0.063-0.313 0.063-0.5 0.313-0.125 0.5-0.188 1.125-0.313 1.875h-0.875l0.063-0.188c0.188-1.25 0.313-2.25 0.438-2.938h0.813l-0.125 0.438c0.188-0.188 0.313-0.313 0.438-0.375 0.125-0.125 0.25-0.125 0.375-0.063zM21.25 14.188l-0.188 0.813c-0.25-0.125-0.5-0.188-0.688-0.188-0.375 0-0.625 0.125-0.813 0.375s-0.25 0.563-0.25 1.063c0 0.313 0.063 0.563 0.188 0.688 0.125 0.188 0.313 0.25 0.563 0.25 0.188 0 0.438-0.063 0.688-0.188l-0.125 0.875c-0.188 0.063-0.438 0.125-0.75 0.125-0.438 0-0.75-0.188-1.063-0.5-0.25-0.25-0.375-0.625-0.375-1.188 0-0.625 0.188-1.188 0.563-1.625 0.313-0.438 0.75-0.688 1.313-0.688 0.188 0 0.5 0.063 0.938 0.188zM23.625 15.688c0 0-0.063 0.125-0.063 0.25s0 0.25 0 0.313c-0.063 0.25-0.125 0.563-0.188 0.938 0 0.375-0.063 0.625-0.125 0.75h-0.625v-0.375c-0.188 0.313-0.5 0.438-0.875 0.438-0.25 0-0.375-0.063-0.5-0.188-0.188-0.188-0.25-0.438-0.25-0.688 0-0.375 0.125-0.688 0.375-0.875 0.313-0.188 0.625-0.313 1.063-0.313h0.313c0.063-0.063 0.063-0.125 0.063-0.188 0-0.188-0.188-0.25-0.5-0.25-0.25 0-0.563 0-0.875 0.125 0-0.188 0-0.438 0.125-0.688 0.375-0.125 0.625-0.188 0.938-0.188 0.75 0 1.125 0.313 1.125 0.938zM22.688 16.5h-0.188c-0.438 0-0.688 0.188-0.688 0.5 0 0.188 0.125 0.313 0.25 0.313 0.188 0 0.313-0.063 0.438-0.188s0.188-0.313 0.188-0.625zM25.625 14.813c-0.125 0.188-0.25 0.5-0.313 0.938-0.188-0.063-0.313 0.063-0.438 0.313s-0.188 0.875-0.375 1.875h-0.813l0.063-0.188c0.188-1 0.313-2 0.375-2.938h0.813c0 0.188-0.063 0.313-0.063 0.438 0.125-0.188 0.25-0.313 0.375-0.375 0.188-0.063 0.313-0.125 0.375-0.063zM27.688 14.063h0.875l-0.688 3.875h-0.75l0.063-0.313c-0.188 0.25-0.438 0.375-0.75 0.375-0.375 0-0.563-0.125-0.688-0.375-0.25-0.25-0.375-0.563-0.375-0.875 0-0.625 0.188-1.063 0.5-1.438 0.188-0.313 0.5-0.5 0.875-0.5 0.313 0 0.563 0.125 0.813 0.375zM27.375 16.125c0-0.375-0.188-0.563-0.438-0.563-0.188 0-0.375 0.063-0.5 0.313-0.063 0.125-0.125 0.375-0.125 0.75s0.125 0.563 0.375 0.563c0.188 0 0.375-0.063 0.5-0.25s0.188-0.438 0.188-0.813z"

# (2) Scale/translate works, after some trial and error


mc_button <- list(
  name = "MasterCard",
  icon = list(
    path = mc_icon_svg_path[[1]]
    ,transform = "scale(0.6 0.6) translate(-3, -2)"
  ),
  click = htmlwidgets::JS(
    "function(gd) {window.open('http://www.mastercard.com', '_blank')}"
  )
)

ggplotly(gg) %>%
  config(modeBarButtonsToAdd = list(mc_button)) %>%
  config(displayModeBar = TRUE) %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender('function(el, x) {
                         $("[data-title=\'MasterCard\'] svg path").css("fill", "#7ac143");
                         $("[data-title=\'MasterCard\'] svg").css("width","2em");
                        }')
```
````

Comment: Note: The code example works if you hit the knit button, but for some reason does not work (with current versions of all sotware and packages) if you run the code chunk. Flagged at [r community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/knitting-my-rmarkdown-works-but-run-code-chunk-does-not/55692)

Comment: Can similar be implemented in Python. I tried but its not working