# Plotly custom modebar icon change color and shape, and open link in a new window from R

Tags: r, plotly

I am using a custom modebar icon to open a link in a new window, and have some related problems

***Problem 1)*** *Custom icon is not a square.* If rescaled to fit in a square would be too small. How do you get it to display properly? To edit in the html that you get after knitting your rmarkdown is straightforward, by right clicking on your icon, and selecting inspect, you can change the width from 1em to 2em to get a wide rectangle.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0  NaN" class="icon" height="1em" width="2em">
```

*How do you control this in R?*

***Problem 2)*** *Custom icon comes in default drab gray.* How to get your preferred color?  To edit in the html that you get after knitting your rmarkdown is straightforward, by right clicking on your icon, and selecting inspect, and adding the style = fill... code below, your color can be used:

```
transform="scale(1) translate(0, -8)" style="fill:#7ac143"></path>
```

*How do you control this in R?* Example code below doesn't use the colour setting.

***Problem 3)*** *Icon has a link which ideally opens in a new window.* The plotly button does open a new window. Example code below for the custom icon doesn't use the "blank" option to open in a new window.

*How can you make this open in a new window?*

````
---
title: "Custom icons in Plotly"
output: html_document
---

```{r echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
    Time = round(runif(10), 2),
    Value = round(runif(10), 2),
    Type = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 5)
    )

gg <- ggplot(data = data) +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = Time, y = Value, colour = Type), size = 2)

# (1) svg path copied from svg file opened in notepad

# logo-mastercard.svg from https://github.com/plotly/plotly-icons/tree/master/src/svg
mc_icon_svg_path = "M29.375 16c0-1.438-0.375-2.813-1.063-4.063-0.75-1.188-1.75-2.125-2.938-2.875-1.313-0.688-2.625-1.063-4-1.063-1.813 0-3.438 0.563-4.875 1.625 1.313 1.188 2.125 2.563 2.563 4.188h-0.75c-0.375-1.375-1.125-2.688-2.313-3.75-1.188 1.063-1.938 2.375-2.313 3.75h-0.75c0.438-1.625 1.25-3 2.563-4.188-1.438-1.063-3.063-1.625-4.875-1.625-1.375 0-2.688 0.375-4 1.063-1.188 0.75-2.188 1.688-2.938 2.875-0.688 1.25-1.063 2.625-1.063 4.063s0.375 2.813 1.063 4.063c0.75 1.188 1.75 2.125 2.938 2.875 1.313 0.688 2.625 1.063 4 1.063 1.813 0 3.438-0.563 4.875-1.625-1.188-1.063-2-2.313-2.5-3.875h0.75c0.438 1.313 1.188 2.5 2.25 3.438 1.063-0.938 1.813-2.125 2.25-3.438h0.75c-0.5 1.563-1.313 2.813-2.5 3.875 1.438 1.063 3.063 1.625 4.875 1.625 1.375 0 2.688-0.375 4-1.063 1.188-0.75 2.188-1.688 2.938-2.875 0.688-1.25 1.063-2.625 1.063-4.063zM6.125 14.063h1.25l-0.625 3.875h-0.813l0.5-2.938-1.063 2.938h-0.625v-2.938l-0.5 2.938h-0.813l0.688-3.875h1.188v2.375zM9.875 15.688c0 0.188-0.063 0.375-0.063 0.563-0.063 0.313-0.125 0.625-0.188 0.875 0 0.25-0.063 0.438-0.125 0.625v0.188h-0.625v-0.375c-0.188 0.313-0.5 0.438-0.875 0.438-0.25 0-0.375-0.063-0.5-0.188-0.188-0.188-0.25-0.438-0.25-0.688 0-0.375 0.125-0.688 0.375-0.875 0.313-0.188 0.688-0.313 1.125-0.313h0.313v-0.188c0-0.188-0.188-0.25-0.563-0.25-0.188 0-0.5 0-0.813 0.125 0-0.188 0.063-0.438 0.125-0.688 0.313-0.125 0.625-0.188 0.938-0.188 0.75 0 1.125 0.313 1.125 0.938zM8.938 16.5h-0.188c-0.438 0-0.688 0.188-0.688 0.5 0 0.188 0.063 0.313 0.25 0.313s0.313-0.063 0.438-0.188c0.125-0.125 0.188-0.313 0.188-0.625zM12.188 14.813l-0.125 0.75c-0.188-0.063-0.375-0.063-0.625-0.063s-0.375 0.063-0.375 0.25c0 0.063 0 0.125 0.063 0.188l0.25 0.125c0.375 0.25 0.563 0.5 0.563 0.875 0 0.688-0.375 1.063-1.25 1.063-0.375 0-0.688-0.063-0.813-0.063 0-0.188 0.063-0.438 0.125-0.75 0.313 0.063 0.563 0.125 0.688 0.125 0.313 0 0.5-0.063 0.5-0.25 0-0.063-0.063-0.188-0.063-0.188-0.125-0.125-0.188-0.188-0.375-0.188-0.375-0.188-0.563-0.5-0.563-0.875 0-0.688 0.375-1.063 1.188-1.063 0.375 0 0.688 0 0.813 0.063zM13.438 14.813h0.375l-0.063 0.813h-0.438c0 0.188-0.063 0.375-0.063 0.563 0 0.063-0.063 0.125-0.063 0.25 0 0.188-0.063 0.25-0.125 0.313v0.25c0 0.188 0.125 0.25 0.313 0.25 0.063 0 0.125 0 0.25-0.063l-0.125 0.75c-0.125 0-0.313 0.063-0.625 0.063-0.438 0-0.625-0.25-0.625-0.688 0-0.25 0-0.563 0.125-0.875l0.313-2.063h0.813zM16.375 15.875c0 0.313 0 0.563-0.063 0.813h-1.625c0 0.188 0.063 0.375 0.125 0.438 0.125 0.125 0.313 0.188 0.563 0.188 0.313 0 0.563-0.063 0.875-0.25l-0.125 0.813c-0.188 0.063-0.5 0.125-0.875 0.125-0.875 0-1.375-0.5-1.375-1.375 0-0.625 0.125-1.063 0.438-1.375 0.25-0.313 0.563-0.5 0.938-0.5s0.688 0.125 0.875 0.313c0.188 0.188 0.25 0.438 0.25 0.813zM14.75 16h0.938v-0.188l-0.063-0.125c0-0.063-0.063-0.125-0.063-0.125-0.063 0-0.125-0.063-0.188-0.063h-0.125c-0.25 0-0.438 0.125-0.5 0.5zM18.438 14.813c-0.063 0.063-0.125 0.375-0.313 0.938-0.188-0.063-0.313 0.063-0.5 0.313-0.125 0.5-0.188 1.125-0.313 1.875h-0.875l0.063-0.188c0.188-1.25 0.313-2.25 0.438-2.938h0.813l-0.125 0.438c0.188-0.188 0.313-0.313 0.438-0.375 0.125-0.125 0.25-0.125 0.375-0.063zM21.25 14.188l-0.188 0.813c-0.25-0.125-0.5-0.188-0.688-0.188-0.375 0-0.625 0.125-0.813 0.375s-0.25 0.563-0.25 1.063c0 0.313 0.063 0.563 0.188 0.688 0.125 0.188 0.313 0.25 0.563 0.25 0.188 0 0.438-0.063 0.688-0.188l-0.125 0.875c-0.188 0.063-0.438 0.125-0.75 0.125-0.438 0-0.75-0.188-1.063-0.5-0.25-0.25-0.375-0.625-0.375-1.188 0-0.625 0.188-1.188 0.563-1.625 0.313-0.438 0.75-0.688 1.313-0.688 0.188 0 0.5 0.063 0.938 0.188zM23.625 15.688c0 0-0.063 0.125-0.063 0.25s0 0.25 0 0.313c-0.063 0.25-0.125 0.563-0.188 0.938 0 0.375-0.063 0.625-0.125 0.75h-0.625v-0.375c-0.188 0.313-0.5 0.438-0.875 0.438-0.25 0-0.375-0.063-0.5-0.188-0.188-0.188-0.25-0.438-0.25-0.688 0-0.375 0.125-0.688 0.375-0.875 0.313-0.188 0.625-0.313 1.063-0.313h0.313c0.063-0.063 0.063-0.125 0.063-0.188 0-0.188-0.188-0.25-0.5-0.25-0.25 0-0.563 0-0.875 0.125 0-0.188 0-0.438 0.125-0.688 0.375-0.125 0.625-0.188 0.938-0.188 0.75 0 1.125 0.313 1.125 0.938zM22.688 16.5h-0.188c-0.438 0-0.688 0.188-0.688 0.5 0 0.188 0.125 0.313 0.25 0.313 0.188 0 0.313-0.063 0.438-0.188s0.188-0.313 0.188-0.625zM25.625 14.813c-0.125 0.188-0.25 0.5-0.313 0.938-0.188-0.063-0.313 0.063-0.438 0.313s-0.188 0.875-0.375 1.875h-0.813l0.063-0.188c0.188-1 0.313-2 0.375-2.938h0.813c0 0.188-0.063 0.313-0.063 0.438 0.125-0.188 0.25-0.313 0.375-0.375 0.188-0.063 0.313-0.125 0.375-0.063zM27.688 14.063h0.875l-0.688 3.875h-0.75l0.063-0.313c-0.188 0.25-0.438 0.375-0.75 0.375-0.375 0-0.563-0.125-0.688-0.375-0.25-0.25-0.375-0.563-0.375-0.875 0-0.625 0.188-1.063 0.5-1.438 0.188-0.313 0.5-0.5 0.875-0.5 0.313 0 0.563 0.125 0.813 0.375zM27.375 16.125c0-0.375-0.188-0.563-0.438-0.563-0.188 0-0.375 0.063-0.5 0.313-0.063 0.125-0.125 0.375-0.125 0.75s0.125 0.563 0.375 0.563c0.188 0 0.375-0.063 0.5-0.25s0.188-0.438 0.188-0.813z"

# (2) Scale/translate works, after some trial and error

# Notes
# (3) Size of viewbox ideally is controlled via here to show rectangular icon neatly.
# (4) Colour control doesn't work
# (5) Open link in new window doesn't work 

mc_button <- list(
    name = "MasterCard",
    icon = list(
        path = mc_icon_svg_path,
        transform = "scale(1) translate(0, -8)",
        style = "fill:#7ac143"
        ),
        click = htmlwidgets::JS(
        "function(gd) {window.location.href = 'http://www.mastercard.com', target='_blank';}"
    )
)

# (6) Some additional customisation
ggplotly(gg) %>%
    config(modeBarButtonsToAdd = list(mc_button)) %>%
    config(displayModeBar = TRUE)
````

Comment: The code example used to work, but now fails with this error ```Error: unexpected symbol in:
"mc_button <- list(
  name = "MasterCard"```. Will try to create a reprex and may post as another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem 1)** I dont really know a good solution for this, except trying to rescale it until its ok. But you can certainly set the width to "2em" using the `htmlwidgets::onRender` method. I use it for changing the fill aswell.

**Problem 2)** You can use `onRender` to change the styling of the *svg path*. Inside the function I define 2 css selectors using the `data-title` *MasterCard*. One for the svg and one for the path inside the svg and then you can change their css settings with Jquery's `css()`.

**Problem 3)** Try to use `window.open` instead. That will open the page in a new tab.

```
mc_button <- list(
  name = "MasterCard",
  icon = list(
    path = mc_icon_svg_path[[1]]
    ,transform = "scale(0.6 0.6) translate(-3, -2)"
  ),
  click = htmlwidgets::JS(
    "function(gd) {window.open('http://www.mastercard.com', '_blank')}"
  )
)

ggplotly(gg) %>%
  config(modeBarButtonsToAdd = list(mc_button)) %>%
  config(displayModeBar = TRUE) %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender('function(el, x) {
                         $("[data-title=\'MasterCard\'] svg path").css("fill", "#7ac143");
                         $("[data-title=\'MasterCard\'] svg").css("width","2em");
                        }')
```

Comment: Do you know if it is true that you must have a single path and accept a single colour for your plotly icon?

Comment: I think for now Plotly only accepts a single path, and therefore you can only assign 1 color to it.